# VideoJS with multiple videos (slideshow) in Firefox

Tags: php, html, wordpress, firefox, video.js

I've been working on a site for a client, it's a WordPress site with Flexslider built-in to the theme. I am trying to get a slideshow of videos working, using VideoJS.

Inside the slideshow.php file, I have got it looping through the given slideshow posts and creating the necessary markup. It generates divs which contain the HTML5 video tag and gives it a unique ID. As the videos which are trying to be played are .mp4 format, and Firefox does not accept this, VideoJS should fallback to the Flash player - which it does, partially.

It seems that every other video on the slideshow works, and the others are left with an empty black box. Note: this is only happening in Firefox; Chrome, IE and Safari are fine, as far as I'm aware.

A live example can be seen here: http://churchcoalition.org/

If anyone has any suggestions for getting all the videos to work in Firefox, it'd be much appreciated.

**Edit: It seems that now, none of the videos are working in FF, despite there being no changes to the code.**

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the neatest way of fixing it, but a fix nevertheless.

I checked the user agent, and if the Firefox string was matched, it would output an  which used another Flash player, and if not, it would use the VideoJS code. I'm still not certain why the Flash fallback on VideoJS is not working, but this fix is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use plugins.Hope that will help you.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpreso-video-featurebox/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/captain-slider/

Comment: Like I said, it's using the Flexslider plugin which is built-in to the theme. The slideshow works, it's just that the videos aren't all working in Firefox. It works in every other browser I've tried.